# Finding the subset of random variables with the best expected max.

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

Given $n$ independent random variables $X_1,..., X_n$ over $[0,1]$ and some natural number $k<n$, find the set of $k$ random variables with the greatest expected maximum value. For precision: $f(S) = max_{i \in S} X_i$ and we want to maximize $f_{avg}(S) = E[f(S)]$ subject to $|S| <= k$.

The greedy approximation of $(1-1/e)$ is immediate since the $f_{avg}$ is submodular and monotone increasing. But I suspect the optimal bound is much better than $1-1/e$. And even suspect that greedy is optimal with a little modification.

I've looked everywhere and thought about this problem for some time now.

Comment: Are the distributions of the $X_i$ known?  By "over $[0,1]$" you mean they are supported in $[0,1]$?  But what if they are all almost always $0$?

Comment: What is this "greedy approximation" supposed to represent?

Comment: Yes the distributions are known. The maximum support they have is [0,1]. The problem is more of a computational question. In the worst case, how do we choose the best subset without computing ${n \choose k)$ expectations. I will edit the question.

Comment: The greedy approximation is the standard way to maximize a submodular function. Use the greedy algorithm: pick the item with the best marginal value for the current set, repeat. Marginal value of item i to set A: f(A \cup i) - f(A)

Comment: But where do you get $1 - 1/e$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function#Submodular_set_function_maximization